# A real mystery with the behavior of SUSER_SID in a simple T-SQL query

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I type the following T-SQL code into a sql query window:

```
-- Get the SUSER_SID standalone
SELECT SUSER_SID('sql_someuser') AS SUSER_SID_OF_SQL_SOMEUSER

-- Get the SUSER_SID as part of a more complex query (should be the same, right?)
SELECT UserSid, UserId FROM User..UserSidToUserId 
UNION ALL
SELECT SUSER_SID('sql_someuser'),12345
```

Here is the result set I get:

[image]

The first two rows of the second result set come straight out of the `UserSidToUserId` table. But that last row, the one with the `UserId` of `12345` that is added by the second query of the `UNION ALL`, the one whose `UserSid` is generated by the second call to `SUSER_SID` with **the exact same user name** is different!

**Update:**
Just so that there is no confusion, here is the definition of the `UserSidToUserId` table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.UserSidToUserId
(
  UserSid uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
  UserId int NOT NULL,
)
```

How can two calls with the same user name to `SUSER_SID` produce results that depend on the context in which `SUSER_SID` is used, given that it is an absolute call that is context independent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `UNION` is converting the second to a string, presumably however you've defined `User..UserSidToUserId.UserSid`. Notice different answers:

```
SELECT SUSER_SID(), CONVERT(VARCHAR(64), SUSER_SID());
```

Comment: Converting `SUSER_SID()` to a `VARCHAR` produces unprintable garbage... This is not the problem. I also added the definition of the `UserSidToUserId` table to the original question.

Comment: It's still a data type difference (I just didn't know what your base table was defined). Why are you using `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`? `SUSER_SID()` is not a GUID - it returns `VARBINARY(85)`. So, your union tries to convert it the `SUSER_SID()` call to a GUID, in order to match your table, based on data type precedence. If you want them to look the same, then change your table definition to `VARBINARY(85)`, or use `CONVERT` directly when calling `SUSER_SID()`.

Comment: Based on the last comment, your solution is correct. So, I will change my table definition and I have accepted your answer... But, I quote from the SQL Server help for SUSER_ID: `If login is a SQL Server login, the SID maps to a GUID.`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that it turns out that the `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` byte order is different from that of a `BINARY` type, with some parts in host byte order and some in network byte order. To make the two results match, you have to do:

```
SELECT (CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,SUSER_SID('sql_someuser'))) 
       AS SUSER_SID_OF_SQL_SOMEUSER_AS_UUID
```

Now it will match the last line of the output of:

```
-- Get the SUSER_SID as part of a more complex query (should be the same, right?)    
SELECT UserSid, UserId FROM User..UserSidToUserId     
UNION ALL    
SELECT SUSER_SID('sql_someuser'),12345
```